# How to write in French when using Constantia font?

Tags: fonts

I can not write some French letters (é, è, â, ...) when I use the font `Constantia`.
This is what I declared before the start of my document:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Constantia}
```

How can I use this font and be able to write in French without a problem ?

Here is the full packages list I loaded:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Constantia}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{array}%for setting cells length
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{wasysym}%for the phone
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Comment: Remove the loading of `inputenc` and of `fontenc`. Where did you download the font?

Comment: I removed them but the error is still there. `Constantia` exists in `fontspec` package

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This one: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:\GenericError {(inputenc)

Comment: You can't get an error from `inputenc` if you don't load it.

Comment: Trust me I commented them

Comment: Perhaps you're loading a class or package that internally loads `inputenc`. You need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Do you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Are you  sure your source file is UTF8 encoded?

Comment: I compile with XeLaTex

Comment: I think you should remove `inputenc` **and** `fontenc` packages. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58761/xelatex-fontspec-restore-original-fonts

Comment: I edited my question to show you all the packages I loaded (and yes, as I said before, I removed `inputenc` and `fontenc` but the problem was there)

Comment: You say you've commented out the two potentially offending packages (`inputenc` and `fontenc`), yet I see them at the very beginning of your edited code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load everything which  depends to a font setting *before* loading `fontspec`. Then it works, at least for me :-)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wasysym}%for the phone
\usepackage[grey,utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Constantia}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}  

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\begin{document}
é, è, â

\end{document}
```

[image]