# LaTeX symbol with original font

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontspec

How to put LaTeX symbol in a document with custom font set as default font?

I'm using **[Source Sans Pro](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/)** as my default text font, when use `\LaTeX` to have its symbol, I get this:

[image]

which is very ugly!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sans serif fonts as default text fonts are ugly. So is \LaTeX in such fonts.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `metalogo` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\begin{document}

{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\LaTeX} % the original

\LaTeX % what you get normally

\setlogokern{La}{-.24em}
\setlogokern{aT}{-.05em}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the picture I set the standard result in Computer Modern, the default one gets with Source Sans Pro and finally the adjusted one.

When you're satisfied with the result, maybe changing also other parameters (check with the documentation of `metalogo`), you can transfer the settings in the document preamble, for instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{metalogo}

\setlogokern{La}{-.24em}
\setlogokern{aT}{-.05em}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: er, the "aT" could be just a bit tighter. and, if i'm "really" being fussy, the "E" could be a tad higher, so that a line drawn between the adjacent right angles of the "TE" is at a 45 degree angle.  (look at the logo on the cover of the texbook.)  the spacing adjustments are very font-dependent.

Answer (score 7):

Small example

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}

\LaTeX

{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont \LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: The ouput of the above Latex code]

see also: [Switching back to Computer Modern within XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/switching-back-to-computer-modern-within-xelatex)