# Default and sporadic fonts

Tags: fonts, default

I am currently working on a document where I want the default font to be, as usual, `Computer Modern`. In particular, unless otherwise specified, this is the font that should be displayed.

Notwithstanding, at some points of the paper, I would like to be able to write a word with the font `bookman`, and then change back to `Computer modern`. I tried to use the advices given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/switching-back-to-computer-modern-within-xelatex), and produced something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\cmr}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\pbk}{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
      \cmr
      \section{Irrational Numbers.}

        Let the set of rational numbers be defined by
    \[\mathbb Q:=\left\{\frac{a}{b} \mid a\in \mathbb Z,  b\in \mathbb N, \gcd(a,b)=1\right\}\]

        \textbf{Claim. } The {\pbk square root} of 2 is irrational.

          \begin{proof}
                 Assume for the sake of contradiction that \ldots
              \end{proof}

    \end{document}
```

[image: produced image]

As you can see in the image, even though `Computer Modern` was set to be the default font at the beginning via `\cmr`, and `bookman` was in fact used when appealing to `\pbk`, the later was also used in several environments such as `\section` or `\begin{proof}`, which was not what I wanted. What have I made wrong? And how could I repare it? Are there easier/alternative proceedings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the line  `\usepackage{bookman}` that file is, in total

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbk}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pag}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

so setting the defaults for the whole document to be bookman, which you don't want.

Also you don't really want

```
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
```

That does nothing as OT1 is the default, but you should almost always use T1 to get correct hyphenation.

Answer (score 2):

You need no `\cmr` command, if you don't load `bookman`, whose main purpose is to set Bookman as the main font.

If you look inside `bookman.sty`, you'll be able to retrieve the LaTeX font family name, that is, `pbk`.

Now you can define commands to switch to this font. I recommend as much abstraction as possible. Comments at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\pbk}{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textpbk}{\pbk}

\newcommand{\memph}[1]{\textpbk{#1}} % change here if needed

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\numberset{Q}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\numberset{Z}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}

\section{Irrational Numbers.}

Let the set of rational numbers be defined by
\[
\QQ:=\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \;\middle|\; a\in \ZZ,  b\in \NN \right\}
\]

\begin{claim}
The \memph{square root} of $2$ is irrational.
\end{claim}

\begin{proof}
Assume for the sake of contradiction that \ldots
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Comments

1. Once you see the output, you should realize that the chosen font is not so good for emphasizing. With the proposed indirection, you can do several experiments *without changing the text inside `document`.
2. Similarly for the number set notation.
3. I removed the condition on the greatest common divisor. My mathematician self screamed when seeing it. I was able to keep him quiet on the choice of not having zero in the natural numbers, but…

Comment: Thanks for the advice! You were right, I should have defined the rational numbers via an equivalence relation, rather than through the `gcd` condition. All in all, 2/4 is a rational number as well :)

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle’s answer, which would give you the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\cmr}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\pbk}{\fontfamily{pbk}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
      \cmr
      \section{Irrational Numbers.}

        Let the set of rational numbers be defined by
    \[\mathbb Q:=\left\{\frac{a}{b} \mid a\in \mathbb Z,  b\in \mathbb N, \gcd(a,b)=1\right\}\]

        \textbf{Claim. } The {\pbk square root} of 2 is irrational.

          \begin{proof}
                 Assume for the sake of contradiction that \ldots
              \end{proof}

    \end{document}
```

works for PDFLaTeX.  In XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you would want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\cmr{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures={Common, TeX}]
\newfontfamily\pbk{TeX Gyre Bonum}[Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]

\begin{document}
      \cmr
      \section{Irrational Numbers.}

        Let the set of rational numbers be defined by
    \[\mathbb Q:=\left\{\frac{a}{b} \mid a\in \mathbb Z,  b\in \mathbb N, \gcd(a,b)=1\right\}\]

        \textbf{Claim. } The {\pbk square root} of 2 is irrational.

          \begin{proof}
                 Assume for the sake of contradiction that \ldots
              \end{proof}

    \end{document}
```

In either, you could add the command

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textbookman{\pbk}

\textbookman{square root}
```