# How can I switch back to Computer Modern in formulas within XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, computer-modern

Answers to the question [Switching back to Computer Modern within XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24994/switching-back-to-computer-modern-within-xelatex) provides a way to switch back to the default font in XeLaTex. However, the solution there doesn't work if I use `\mathrm` in a formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\newfontfamily\lmodern{Latin Modern Roman} % If font exists on your system
% Optical sizes need to be set up manually using the [SizeFeatures] option
% or select the font using the regular font selection methods
\newcommand{\lmr}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont} % Latin Modern Roman
\newcommand{\lmss}{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont} % Latin Modern Sans
\newcommand{\lmtt}{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont} % Latin Modern Mono
\begin{document}
\[\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}+1=0\]
{\lmr\[\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}+1=0\]}
\end{document}
```

You can see that the letters e and i are still not in the default font. Using some other fonts will make formulas look even worse, such as Consolas.

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Off topic, but are you aware of the [libertinus fonts](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-fonts?lang=en), that also include an OpenType math font?

Comment: I agree with mickep, but if you do not want libertinus for some reasong: Why not using package [`libertine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) to load Linux Libertine? It works out of the box with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: And if you want to setup (a different) math font with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I would suggest [`unicode-math`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep Latin Modern as the default text and math font, don't execute `\setmainfont` instructions. Conversely, if you do want to switch the main text font to Linux Libertine O, you should probably load the `unicode-math` package and execute `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`. On the other hand, if you want Libertine for text-mode material but Latin Modern for math-mode material, you may want to replace `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}` with `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]`.

[image]

```
%% execute this test file under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}+1=0$

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % or Scale=MatchUppercase
$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}+1=0$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @cabohah points out in a comment, `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` may not work with some TeX distribution/operating system combinations. If that's an issue for you, it may be preferable to load the `libertine`, `libertinus`, or `libertinus-otf` packages instead of executing `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` instructions.

Comment: Why not loading package `libertine` resp. `libertinus` resp. `libertinus-otf`? `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` usually does not work out of the box with XeLaTeX from Vanilla TeX Live but the packages do.

Comment: @cabohah - Thanks for this. I've posted an addendum to mention the points you've made.